# How to handle contracts in libraries when forking Uniswap?

Tags: solidity, dapps, uniswap, chainlink, project-fork

I am creating a DEX by forking Uniswap.

If I fork `Uniswap V3` then do I need to re-deploy all contracts in `libraries` folder?

Q 2: How Uniswap calculates the price of a token? Does it get it from Chainlink's price feed?

Comment: I suggest you ask the second question on a separate post as it is not related with the first one. Uniswap does not use Chainlink for prices. You can find more information about Uniswap pricing here: https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/concepts/advanced-topics/pricing

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to "re-deploy" all contracts in `libraries` folder. You only have to deploy `UniswapV3Factory`.

All the imports the contract has are automatically taken care of for you and added as part of the source code.

So, when you say...

```
import './UniswapV3Pool.sol';
```

...you are also importing all the imports that are included in this smart contract.

This means that you are also importing all the...

```
import './libraries/*
```

...that appear listed there.

The address you will get after successfully deploying `UniswapV3Factory` will be the address of a smart contract that not only "understands" all the `UniswapV3Factory` methods but also the methods of all the smart contracts that it inherites (`IUniswapV3Factory`, `UniswapV3PoolDeployer` and `NoDelegateCall`).

Comment: Thanks, tell me one thing that there are multiple contracts in `contracts` folder except libraries and interfaces, as u mentioned too, if i only deploy `uniswapV3Factory.sol` then how other related contracts will syncronize with the factory contract, they are not deployed so how their methods will work?

Comment: They will synchronise because they will be part of ’UniswapV3Factory‘ as this contract inherits the others. So technically they are deployed as part of it. That's why you also get those methods.